# Tab Key doesn't indent in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When programming in VS Code, I always use the Tab key for indenting. But, I was surprised that is stopped working all of a sudden. How do I fix this?

Comment: If you have enabled the "Tab Moves Focus" -mode, try pressing `Ctrl + M`, and then try if the tab key works correctly.

Comment: that is one of the WORST features EVER.  I have been triple spacing my lines all day because >>>>TAB<<<< wont work.   Now I have to go fix it all.     WHOSE IDEA WAS THAT?   thanks for the help!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You have enabled the Tab Moves Focus -mode.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to disable the mode. After that your <kbd>Tab</kbd>-key indents your code again.